# Oracle automatic partitioning - name pattern for partitions

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, partitioning

I will be using automatic partitioning from Oracle 11g and I am wondering **is there any option to give partition name specific pattern?**

For example I have:

```
create table 
pos_data ( 
   start_date        DATE,
   store_id          NUMBER,
   inventory_id      NUMBER(6),
   qty_sold          NUMBER(3),
) 
PARTITION BY RANGE (start_date) 
INTERVAL(NUMTOYMINTERVAL(1, 'MONTH')) 
(  
   PARTITION pos_data_init VALUES LESS THAN (TO_DATE('01-01-2017', 'DD-MM-YYYY')),
   PARTITION pos_data_201702 VALUES LESS THAN (TO_DATE('01-02-2017', 'DD-MM-YYYY')),
   PARTITION pos_data_201703 VALUES LESS THAN (TO_DATE('01-03-2017', 'DD-MM-YYYY')),
);
```

I will have init partition to have all rows before 2017 and then partitions for each month.

How will be named partitions that will be automaticly generated?
Is there any chance to create pattern that the end of name will be YYYYMM? Or I have to rename those partitions later?

Comment: You can use PLSQL with dynamic SQL to archive pattern based naming

Comment: So there is only scirpt-way and automaticly generated names are just bumping up the value at the and like part1, part2, part3 etc.?

Comment: @Sarpens if you're using interval partitioning, then you are stuck with the names that get generated by the database. As GurV suggests, if you need a certain naming pattern then you will need to write your own code to retrospectively rename the partitions

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, there is no such option that allows you to specify partition name pattern for dynamically created partitions. You can/should rename them later if such a need arises. Personally I see no need in renaming them. if you want to give those automatically generated partitions meaningful names so you can reference them in a query, for example:

```
select *
  from partitioned_table
  partition (part_1);
```

then you can easily use `partition for (<<date>>)` clause to query a specific partition, which does not require you to know a partition name you want to query:

```
select *
  from partitioned_table
  partition for (date '2017-01-01')
```

Comment: Now I get it all! Thanks for the answer! Just old way partitioning that I review here was creating with specific name pattern and just wondering if I can get same result with automatic way. Best wishes for New Year : )

Answer (score 1):

I use this procedure to rename partitions which is executed once per day by scheduler job:

```
FUNCTION DailyPartition(tableName IN VARCHAR2) RETURN BOOLEAN IS

    EXPRESSION_IS_OF_WRONG_TYPE EXCEPTION;
    PRAGMA EXCEPTION_INIT(EXPRESSION_IS_OF_WRONG_TYPE, -6550);

    ds INTERVAL DAY TO SECOND;
    ym INTERVAL YEAR TO MONTH;
    str VARCHAR2(1000);

BEGIN    
    SELECT INTERVAL INTO str 
    FROM USER_PART_TABLES 
    WHERE TABLE_NAME = tableName;

    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'BEGIN :ret := '||str||'; END;' USING OUT ym;
    RETURN FALSE;    
EXCEPTION 
    WHEN EXPRESSION_IS_OF_WRONG_TYPE THEN
        EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'BEGIN :ret := '||str||'; END;' USING OUT ds;
        RETURN TRUE;    
END DailyPartition;


PROCEDURE RenamePartitions IS

    ts TIMESTAMP;
    newName VARCHAR2(30);

    CURSOR TabPartitions IS
    SELECT TABLE_NAME, PARTITION_NAME, HIGH_VALUE
    FROM USER_TAB_PARTITIONS 
    WHERE TABLE_NAME IN ('YOUR_TABLE', ...)
        AND PARTITION_NAME <> 'P_INITIAL'
    ORDER BY 1,2;

BEGIN

    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'ALTER SESSION SET DDL_LOCK_TIMEOUT = 180';

    FOR aPart IN TabPartitions LOOP
        EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'BEGIN :ret := '||aPart.HIGH_VALUE||'; END;' USING OUT ts;
        IF DailyPartition(aPart.TABLE_NAME) THEN            
            ts := ts - INTERVAL '1' DAY;
            newName := 'P_'||TO_CHAR(ts,'yyyy_mm_dd');
        ELSE
            ts := ADD_MONTHS(ts, -1);
            newName := 'P_'||TO_CHAR(ts,'yyyy_mm');
        END IF;
        IF aPart.PARTITION_NAME <> newName THEN             
            EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'ALTER TABLE '||aPart.TABLE_NAME||' RENAME PARTITION '||aPart.PARTITION_NAME||' TO '||newName;
        END IF;
    END LOOP;

END RenamePartitions;
```